# Correct shapes for Keras Training

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

I'm loading dataset from CSV to Tensorflow, Keras.
CSV is structured so, that first 63 elements are inputs, the rest 3 is outputs.
I don't properly understand shapes in Python, therefore I would be glad if somebody provided more info on what I'm doing wrong here.

From errors I understand, that I must set output size to 3 somewhere, but I clearly don't understand how.

```
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
```

This is y's `print(y)`, it should be array of 3's but is one. Possibly this is the mistake, so how to shape it properly? Thank you. I googled something, but it's not working.

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense


dataset = loadtxt('./dataset.csv', delimiter=';')
x = dataset[:,0:63]
y = dataset[:,63]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(96, input_shape=(63, ), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(63, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(47, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(23, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(23, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=231, batch_size=420)
```

I think everything is all right, but I get following error:

```
Epoch 1/231
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arre/Code/Python/ML/Ground0/ml.py", line 19, in <module>
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=231, batch_size=420)
  File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filesrua8cms.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1024, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 152, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 284, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2176, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/home/arre/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5680, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 3) vs (None, 1)).
```

Comment: Are you sure you meant to use `y = dataset[:,63]` and not `y = dataset[:,63:]` ?

Comment: You fixed it, thank you.